# "Open with..." in Eclipse without switching default editor

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I often need to use two editors in Eclipse for one file. One of the editors is slower though, so no matter how many times I use it, I want the other editor to be the default. The "Open with" option lets me switch editors, but in my environment, it also switches the default editor for that file. How can I use Open with without switching default editors?

Answer (score 0):

You can set default editors for a given file type. Go to Window-Preferences and search for file associations.

[image]

You can add your file type using Add button and add editors for that file type in the below text area. Every thing else in the picture is self explanatory.

### Note:

Initially double clicking on any file will open that file in associated default editor. As show in the above picture. Once you used `Open with` command to open it in different editor then this new editor is considered as default editor for that file type and hence forth double clicking on this file type will open that file in recently used editor.

Thus use frequently used editor as default editor for a given file type and use open with option when you want to switch to other type of editors.

Comment: My question was "How can I use Open with without switching default editors?" Is this answer saying basically "you can't?" :(

Comment: AFAIK yes. You can't.